# SCGI vs FastCGI - Which one is faster?

Tags: web-server, fastcgi, cgi

I want to use one of servers - libscgi and libfcgi - with dynamic content. Which one seems to be faster?

Comment: Looking at the protocol definitions, SCGI uses a simpler protocol which requires less parsing. However, the differences in overall performance are likely negligible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between FastCGI and SCGI is miniature, as SCGI is essentially just a “simpler FastCGI''. As the web server support for SCGI is limited, most people use FastCGI instead, which works the same way. Almost everything that applies to SCGI also applies to FastCGI as well.

FastCGI and SCGI try to solve the performance problem of CGI in another way. Instead of embedding the interpreter into the web server, they create long-running background processes.

FastCGI is technically more resilient and robust, and that's probably the reason why it is more widely deployed than SCGI.

[1] https://docs.python.org/2/howto/webservers.html#fastcgi-and-scgi